# How to upgrade package from a different release?

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04, zabbix

I upgrade a server from 16.04 to 18.04.

After the final reboot, I re-activated the additional source list which have been disable during the update. (It was Zabbix repository)

Then I upgrade the system, but did not notify about new upgrade.

However the version installed was for xenial and a version for bionic is available to work properly. (same version).

When I tried to :

- update : no new version available
- reinstall : unable to locate package (seems logic because I replace xenial by bionic)
- Manually install the bionic version :  The system consider the current version (xenial) the latest

I finally remove and install the packages.

But I would like to know what is the proper way to upgrade package from a Ubuntu version to another and avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a mistake of the repository maintainer to have assigned the same version string to the Xenial and Bionic versions of the package, for exactly the reason you are now facing.

You should report the problem to them, and in the meantime you can either remove the Xenial version and install the Bionic one, or just keep the Xenial version for now if it is not causing issues (when a new version is released, the Bionic one will be installed).

Answer (score 0):

although I know the question is not new, I assume it is still valid in general so I'd like to add an alternative that did work for me for reference:

You may explicitly define the expected version name to the `apt install` command. In my case (`nginx=1.16.0-1~xenial` vs. `nginx=1.16.0-1~bionic`) I had the very same situation that Ubuntu did not upgrade from the Xenial package to the Bionic one, as it assumes it to be downgrade (probably related to the alpha-numeric sorting 'x' vs. 'b'?!). Anyhow, this solved it for me:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep '^.i' | grep nginx
ii  nginx    1.16.0-1~xenial    amd64    high performance web server
$ sudo apt-get install nginx=1.16.0-1~bionic
$ dpkg -l | grep '^.i' | grep nginx
ii  nginx    1.16.0-1~bionic    amd64    high performance web server
```

Hope this helps anyone.